# LVDS Interface - Output Max Swing is Higher than Max Input Swing

Tags: voltage, interface, lvds

I am connecting together two "LVDS" devices. The specs are as follows:

Output: VoDiff = 247-600 mV, Vcm = 1-1.485 (1.25 typ)
Input: VinDiff = 100-500 mV, Vcm = 1-1.6 (1.25 typ)

So for the most part they look compatible. However I am wondering if I should be concerned that the output can swing up to 600 mV and the input is rated up to 500 mV. Is this a concern?

The input has two 50 ohms to GND with a mid voltage of 1.25. So I am guessing I do not need any termination, but just concerned about the voltage swing.

[LVDS receiver - Teledyne e2v EV12DS480A 12-bit, 8 GSps DAC](https://www.teledyne-e2v.com/shared/content/resources/File/documents/Semiconductors/EV12DS480A/DS%2060S%20217580_EV12DS480A_rev%20A.5.pdf)

[LVDS driver - Xilinx  Kintex UltraScale XQRKU060 FPGA. Please see p.27](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds882-xqr-kintex-ultrascale.pdf)

Comment: "the output can swing up to 600mv and the input is rated up to 500mV. Is this a concern?"... if your transmission path consumes the 100mv difference at minimal output current of your transmitter - No

Comment: @schnedan This is not how LVDS works. It's a current loop that drives a current into a 100 ohms load.

Comment: Too short for an answer: There shouldn't be a problem if you use proper termination and the maximal voltage on either of the wires is always lower than the receivers input driver voltage. But details may depend on the specific devices.

Comment: @asdfex I worked with an LVDS based System for 10years... I know what I say

Comment: Under what condition(s) is the VoDiff = 247-600 mV specified? LVDS is a constant current, +/- 3.5 mA drive.  When terminated in 100 ohms (typical for high speed diff interfaces), this gives us the nominal Vdiff of +/- 350 mV.  The only way the input would see greater than 350 mV diff voltage is with a parallel termination of 170 ohms or greater.

Comment: I added the link to the datasheet above. Sorry I am new to this

Comment: The 600mV max swing is specified with Rt= 100 ohms across the terminals

Comment: @Matty - How do you conclude that the VinDiff is 500 mV max?  On page 3 of the data sheet it says that the absolute max rating for the diff inputs is 2V p-p.

Comment: I am looking at Vid on p.5 to get the 500mV max swing?

Comment: @Matty - How 'bout the data sheet for the driving device - the one that says a max output voltage swing of 600 mV, with 100 ohms termination?

Comment: @Stevesh. I added the datasheet for the driving device. Please see p.27

Comment: @Matty - Looks like the Kintex part doesn't meet the limits of the LVDS standard (ANSI/TIA/EIA-644-A), which specifies a max diff output of 454 mV.  The Teledyne DAC does meet the spec.  I would ask a Xilinx FAE under what conditions the 600 mV might be seen.  And I would ask Teledyne the impacts if the LVDS inputs are overdriven by 150 mV.  I don't think there is the possibility of any damage to the DAC, but some of the performance may be compromised by the overdrive.